# Simple SQL format

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help me with a simple sql tag please??

Here's what I want:

```
Select * from table1 where transid='select transid from table2 where date='01/02/2003''
```

How to have it in proper sql format?

Comment: `'01/02/2003'` is ambiguous. Try using `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YYYYMMDD'` format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Select * 
from table1 
where transid=(select transid from table2 where date='01/02/2003')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Select * from table1
  where transid in 
    (select transid from table2 where date='01/02/2003')
```

Answer (score 4):

Or just do a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  table1.*
FROM    table1
JOIN    table2
ON      table1.transid=table2.transid
    AND date = '01/02/2003'
```